# First Time Visitor Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

For my site, I want to create a link in the middle of the page for first time visitors that says something like "First time, click here" using PHP.

Comment: If the user doesn't have a "not first time" cookie, display the message, then set the cookie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could in theory do it with cookies, but there's no guaranteed way to detect "first time visitors" other than asking them to register for an account and show them the message the first time they log in.

The reason is that cookies may get cleaned from the browser, people may change computers / browsers, cookies will eventually expire and depending on what your goal is you may end up annoying existing users assuming they're new.

Anyway, enough of that. Your code could look something like this:

```
<?php
    // Top of the page, before sending out ANY output to the page.
        $user_is_first_timer = !isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] );

    // Set the cookie so that the message doesn't show again
        setcookie( "FirstTimer", 1, strtotime( '+1 year' ) );
?>




<H1>hi!</h1><br>


<!-- Put this anywhere on your page. -->
<?php if( $user_is_first_timer ): ?>
    Hello there! you're a first time user!.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: For some reason, it always says I'm a first time visitor, even after I've refreshed the page several times.

Comment: Hey @Ryan, there was a typo in the order of parameters of setcookie().. I've fixed the post and tested the code... give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a function that creates the cookie on the "click", and prompt everyone that does not have a cookie.

[Setting a cookie is pretty trivial in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['firsttimer'])){
    // ok, lets set the cookie
    setcookie('firsttimer','something',strtotime('+1 year'),'/');
    $_COOKIE['firsttimer']='something'; // cookie is delayed, so we do this fix
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['firsttimer']){
    // if cookie ain't set, show link
    echo '<a href="?firsttimer">First time, click here</a>';
}else{
    // not firsttimer
    echo 'Welcome back!';
}
```

Comment: when I tried this it always showed me as a first time user even after I refreshed my browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// this might go best in the new visitor file
setcookie('visited','yes', 0x7FFFFFFF); // expires at the 2038 problem point

// ... snip ...

if (isset($_COOKIE['visited'])):
?>
<a href="foo.php">New Visitor?  Click here!</a>
<?php
endif;

// ... snip ...
```

Comment: how can this be changed so I can have the link in the middle of the page somewhere?

Comment: just break the two segments into different files; put the `setcookie` statement at the top of the page you want them to visit, and put the `if (isset())` portion right where you want the link.