# How can I check if a user enters my page the first time?

Tags: perl, cookies

I wrote the following subroutine to set cookie for new users who come to my website for the first time

```
Sub setcookie {
$cookie_id = localtime();
$exp = "Fri, 31-Sep-2015 24:00:00 GMT";
if($ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'} eq "") {
        print "Set-Cookie: first_access=$cookie_id; expires=$exp; PATH=/; domain=mysite.com\n";
 }
}
```

Whenever user hits "purchase" to buy any items from my shop, the script will check if user already has cookie. If not, display the login form. This is the step that I've been stuck on.

```
&setcookie;
if ($form{submit} eq "Purchase")
    if (!= cookieForuser)
        &displayloginform;
    else
         &checkoutform;
```

How do I write another sub called `cookieForuser` to implement the said idea?

Comment: Check this post, it may give you some good pointers:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722990/first-time-visitor-cookie

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I don't know PHP @@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do you a favor and use at least the [CGI module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html), it will make your life much easier and *safer*.

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Cookie;

%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
if ( exists $cookies{VISITED} ) {
    checkoutform();
}
else {
    my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'VISITED',-value=>1,
        -expires='Fri, 31-Sep-2015 24:00:00 GMT');
    print header(-cookie=>[$cookie]);
    displayloginform();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that [the CGI module will be removed from core Perl 5 version 22](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/05/ejecting-cgipm-from-the-perl-core.html).

Comment: @Jose Rey: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot. One more thing, is there any way to hide this info `Set-Cookie: VISITED=1; path=/; expires=Tue, 25-Nov-2014 02:57:57 GMT Date: Mon, 24 Nov 2014 02:57:57 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` ? It is shown right above my login form...